# EXE exports static lib exports as well

Tags: c++, pe-exports

I've created both a static lib and an EXE file (which uses the static lib), but when I open up the EXE in IDA pro, the exports are listed in the EXE as well.

I know they should be exported in the .lib itself, but why are they showing up as exports in the EXE too?

EDIT: Here is an export/import (they are in *separate header files*)

Here is the export:

```
#define NC_LIBEXPORT(a) extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) a __cdecl
NC_LIBEXPORT(VOID) rol8(unsigned char* a, unsigned char b);
```

and the import:

```
extern "C" VOID rol8(unsigned char* a, unsigned char b);
```

Comment: It doesn't come from the header file, the attribute is attached to the identifier in the .obj file inside the .lib.  You would have to build a special version of the .lib that prevents the __declspec being applied.  Not so sure that's worth it if you also link the .lib into a DLL, it's not like any code is actually going to use the export.

Comment: @Hans Yes, I just worked that out the slow way. By building a test project!

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant :] That did it! Didn't realize static libs don't need `dllexport` :] Two static libs is, for this project, fine with me. Just a macro edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that when you build the static lib, you do not use `__declspec(dllexport)`.

If you want to use the same lib in a DLL and in your executable, and you don't want the executable to export the symbols, then you'll need to use a DEF file rather than `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: I'm using the import (the second code block) in my executable.

Comment: @Di-0xide Yes, Hans knew that off the top of his head. I had to experiment in VS to work it out.